# Prevent android webview from displaying error page

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I would like to display local HTML from asset if the error was received. However, even if I override onReceivedError method, before the page from asset will display, there is an error page flashing for a second. Is there a fix or hack for this issue yet?

Here is my code:

```
    @Override
    public void onReceivedError (WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
    {
        Log.i("onReceivedError", "onReceivedError: " + failingUrl + " errorCode: " + errorCode);
        super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
        view.stopLoading();
        loadFromAsset(view, failingUrl);
    }
```

Comment: What error do you have in mind? `onReceivedError` handles HTTP response status codes. From documentation: `Report an error to the host application. ... Basic usage: ..does not enable JavaScript and web page errors are ignored`

Comment: I mean the default Android "Page Not Found" error. You know - if there is no Internet connection, I would like to display page from asset instead of error page.

Comment: here is something about it: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=968

Comment: Quote: `the errors are not HTTP errors but are 
unrecoverable resource errors (file not found, no network connection, server not found for the main resource, 
etc.).`

Comment: You can use `HttpClient` instead and handle `HttpResponse.getStatusLine.getStatusCode`

Comment: Could you tell me more details? Here is the same problem: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2340 but there is no solution to avoid flashing.

Comment: you could try something like: `onPageStarted{ view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); }` and then `onPageFinished{ view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); }` in order to avoid flicker

Comment: unfortunately, this hack of @Mocialov Boris does not work for me. any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to bypass this issue by checking if there is internet connection in onPageStarted event, for now it seems to be working on all devices we tested so far. I'm using custom html error page.

```
 mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            if(!NetworkConnection.isNetworkAvailable(getActivity()) && !url.equals("file:///android_asset/error_page.html")){
                view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error_page.html");
            }
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error_page.html");
            super.onReceivedError(view,errorCode,description,failingUrl);
        }

    });
```

Comment: is there a difference between calling `loadUrl()` once on `view` (received as parameter) and once on `mWebView` (view on which setWebViewClient is called) ?